# Fill a dictionary with all cell values of given row

Tags: python, pyqt4, cell, qtablewidget

User sets values manually in all cells in a QTableWidget. The values of the first row of the table represent the values we want to store in a dictionary `FirstRowDict`. Second row values will be put in `SecondRowDict` and so on.

[image]

So from a table like one shown in the picture,
we want to end up in this example with `FirstRowDict={0:10,1:20}`
and `SecondRowDict={0:30,1:40}`

To achieve this i created a button and added an action that updates the target dictionaries when clicked:

```
def button_click():
    for j in range(0,2):
        FirstRowDict.update({i: float(str(tablewidget.itemAt(0,j).text()))})

        #I put "0" in itemAt because first row is zero
        #tablewidget = QTableWidget() declared earlier in the source code

        SecondRowDict.update({i: float(str(tablewidget.itemAt(1,j).text()))})

    print '1st_Row_Dict=%s'%1st_Row_Dict,'\n2nd_Row_Dict=%s'%2nd_Row_Dict
```

***The output is not correct since the dictionaries are populated with same value and not the unique value of each cell.***
I get `FirstRowDict={0:10,1:10}` and `SecondRowDict={0:10,1:10}`

It seems that i have to create a new item using [QTableWidgetItem](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtablewidget.html#item) http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtablewidget.html#item

Python begginer, some advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get as output? BTW, `1st_Row_Dict` is not a valid name in Python.

Comment: This is what i get:FirstRowDict={0:10,1:10}, SecondRowDict={0:10,1:10} .I edited the dictionary names because i just picked these names for the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I see the confusion. `itemAt` returns the item at the given position, but it's not `row/column`. It's the coordinate (think of it as pixel).

Yes, you should use `item` instead of `itemAt`.

You don't need a `str` if you're going to convert it to float. `float()` will work on a `QString` as if it was a `str`. And, instead of `.update`, you can just assign the new value to the key.

```
FirstRowDict[i] = float(tablewidget.item(0, j).text())
```